# Will this damage my PC? GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer pci=nomsi"

Tags: grubrescue, pci

When I tried to install my Ubuntu 16.04.2 I faced with no screen problem! and PCI_bus errors! after many searching and trying only this modifications on `/etc/default/grub` solved my problem:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer pci=nomsi"
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text pci=noaer pci=nomsi"

When I tried each one(pci=nomsi or pci=noaer) alone, it didn't work! and only this modification worked!

And the other strange thing is, I before had installed this ubuntu on this laptop without any problems! but this time I faced this problem!

By the way, it works nice at now, and I want to know what do these changes do and is it possible to damage my laptop?

EDIT: After restarting my computer I encountered to the problem again (a violet blank locked screen, after choosing ubuntu from grub menu) and I forced to shutdown my pc by power key! then after turning it on it worked good!

I don't know what is this strange problem and how can I fix it?